# ([NSThread isMainThread]) exception MBProgressHUD

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I have been getting this error when trying to present the contact book view controller after a long process is complete.

Here is how I am running the process and showing the `HUD`.

```
    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    HUD.labelText = @"Scanning...";
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20];
    [HUD setLabelFont:font];
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(scanWithImage:) onTarget:self withObject:_image animated:YES];
```

Here is how I am hiding the HUD and showing the contact book vc, which is called in `scanImage`.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [HUD hide:YES];

});
[self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Full error message:

`Assertion failed: ([NSThread isMainThread]), function -[AFContextManager addContextProvider:], file /SourceCache/MobileAssistantFramework/MobileAssistantFramework-651.49/AFContextManager.m, line 113.`

Comment: I am using OpenCV, and tesseract. However in debug it runs over those code segments fine, its when the adressbook VC is being displayed. It displays the top nav bar of the address book but then crashes right away. I think it might be trying to display the VC before the process is complete but not sure. Oh you deleted your comment :(.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to present the new controller from the background thread. Anything with respect to User interface including presenting a new controller cannot be performed from the background thread. So present the new controller from the main thread. Try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [HUD hide:YES];
[self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];

});
```